# How to use function(index) in the function wrap() of javascript?

Tags: jquery

In [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_wrap.asp) website, it says that the syntax of `wrap()` is:

```
$(selector).wrap(wrappingElement,function(index))
```

with `function(index)` being optional, which specifies a function that returns the wrapping element. The "index" returns the index position of the element in the set.

How is the function specified? What does it mean by "index returns the index position of the element in the set"? How should one use this optional argument? (The examples on this website do not use function(index) in the argument of the function wrap().)

An example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` refers to a parameter that the callback in the `wrap` function is expecting. This is normally documented in the documentation related to the function you are trying to use.

The callback is executed when the `wrap()` function has finished running. Hence is will pass through a `index` variable into the callback.

As documented in the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/#wrap-wrappingElement) documentation

> **function**
>   Type: Function( Integer index ) => String or jQuery
>   A callback function returning the HTML content or jQuery object to wrap around the matched elements. Receives the index position of the element in the set as an argument. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to some examples.

Comment: It seems that every example in the link also doesn't contain the second argument though.

Comment: It appears that the wrap function in jQuery does not take a second argument.

Comment: It does according to this website: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_wrap.asp